# How to get the remote hostname in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am looking to resolve the hostname of the remote client in a Ruby on Rails app.

I know that `Request.remote_ip` will give me the client's IP address, but how do I translate that to their hostname?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out!

Here's a method I put in my ApplicationHelper:

```
def remote_hostname
  require 'resolv'
  Resolv.getname(request.remote_ip)
end
```

Simple as that!

Answer (score -1):

Try as follow;

```
require 'socket'
host = Socket.gethostname
```

or you can simply do;

```
`hostname`.strip # Get the hostname from the shell and removing trailing \n
```

Comment: I think he's after the *remote* hostname, not the local one.